# Flash Builder 4.6. Soft Keyboard is not working

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

Flash builder 4.6 this is my text input code

```
<s:TextInput skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" softKeyboardType="contact" needsSoftKeyboard="true" y="98" right="41" width="282" height="39" />
```

not working, what is problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, normally I would recommend that you quantify what "not working" means.  Do you get runtime errors?  Or compile time errors?  Or unexpected behavior?  In this case, I think I guessed it and posted an answer.  We are here to help, not to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The softKeyboardType values only apply if you are using StageText.  It appears you are using the Flex 4.5 TextInput skin; which does not make use of StageText, but rather the Flash TextField.

[Quote](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextInput.html)

> The TextInput skin for the mobile theme uses the StyleableStageText
>   class instead of RichEditableText. Since StyleableStageText uses
>   native text fields it allows for better text entry and manipulation
>   experiences on mobile devices however there are limitations and
>   differences that you should consider. The native text controls used by
>   StageText apply different paddings around text. In order to avoid
>   vertical scrolling, the StageText-based TextInput skin attempts to
>   estimate this padding and compensate for that. Because of this and
>   other differences in how native text controls treat text, the default
>   height of the TextInput control using StageText-based skin will differ
>   from its default height using the the TextField-based TextInput skin.